# What are the bash commands to setup or recognize a MySQL installation on a Mac?

Tags: bash, anaconda

first post on so; let me know any advice on better asking

Anyways, my current bash profile is:

```
# added by Anaconda3 2019.10 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!

__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<


‘export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH'
```

I was getting this info from the tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXV3zeQKqGY , ~1 hour 7 mins in.

I don't have a conda env activated right now. Anyone have an idea why when I type "mysql" into my bash terminal I am returned "command not found"?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a problem with you `$PATH`.

Open `.bash_profile`. and then Place `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin` in it.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick thanks a ton.  Was the single quote around ```‘export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH'``` causing the issue as well?

Comment: @ajp.gp4life you should use `'` instead  of  ( ` ).  your first single quote seems incorrect. If you like my solution please accept by clicking on tick mark.